# A problem about projective operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $P$ and $Q$ be projective on a Hilbert space $H$. Show that $P+Q$ is projective if and only if $\mbox{ran }P \perp \mbox{ran }Q$.
The sufficiency is easy. About the necessity, suppose $P+Q$ is projective. It's sufficient to prove $$ PQ=0 $$ and for $P+Q$ is idempotent we have $$ PQ+QP=0 $$ And I don't how to use the condition that $P+Q$ is projective.

Comment: What's your precise definition of projective? Idempotent and self-adjoint?

Answer (score 4):

Since $P+Q=(P+Q)^2$, we get $P+Q=P+Q+PQ+QP$, so $PQ+QP=0$. Multiplying by $P$ both left and right, we get $2PQP=0$, so $PQP=0$. Now we use that $P^*=P$, $Q^*=Q$: 
$$
0=PQP=PQQP=P^*Q^*QP=(QP)^*QP,
$$
so $QP=0$. Then $0=\langle QPx,y\rangle=\langle Px,Qy\rangle$ for any $x,y$, showing that the ranges are orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you! This is really useful! As if the sufficient condition of $ran P \bot ran Q$ is that the $P+Q$ is idempotent when $P and Q$ are projective whit no need for it's projective.

Comment: We don't really know what you mean by "projective". But note that if $P,Q$ are both selfadjoint, then so is $P+Q$.

Comment: I mean P+Q is a projection which is both idempotent and selfadjoint.